# Not able to sort in ascending and descending

Tags: mongodb

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6068b4d1ba926fd240c5216e"), "name" : "Rohit", "branch" : "CSE", "joiningYear" : 2018, "language" : [ "C#", "Python", "Java" ], "personal" : { "contactinfo" : 0, "state" : "Delhi", "age" : 24, "semestermarks" : [ 70, 73.3, 76.5, 78.9 ] }, "salary" : 1000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6068b4d1ba926fd240c5216f"), "name" : "Amit", "branch" : "ECE", "joiningYear" : 2017, "language" : [ "Python", "C#" ], "personal" : { "contactinfo" : 234556789, "state" : "UP", "age" : 25, "semestermarks" : [ 80, 80.1, 98, 70 ] }, "salary" : 10000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6068b4d1ba926fd240c52170"), "name" : "Sumit", "branch" : "CSE", "joiningYear" : 2017, "language" : [ "Java", "Perl" ], "personal" : { "contactinfo" : 2300056789, "state" : "MP", "age" : 24, "semestermarks" : [ 89, 80.1, 78, 71 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606ac8d9a4cfca3993d52732"), "name" : "Mohit", "branch" : "EEE", "joiningYear" : 2019, "language" : [ "Python", "PhP", "Java" ], "personal" : { "contactinfo" : 489395205, "state" : "Rajasthan", "age" : 23, "semesterMarks" : [ 75.6, 74, 86, 50 ] }, "salary" : 20000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606ac8d9a4cfca3993d52733"), "name" : "Krant", "branch" : "ECE", "joiningYear" : 2017, "language" : [ "C++", "Java", "R" ], "personal" : { "contactinfo" : 489395455, "state" : "Gujrat", "age" : 26, "semesterMarks" : [ 55.6, 64, 46, 50 ] }, "salary" : 10000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606ac8d9a4cfca3993d52734"), "name" : "Jitesh", "branch" : "CSE", "joiningYear" : 2018, "language" : [ "C#", "PhP", "Java" ], "personal" : { "contactinfo" : 666795205, "state" : "Tamil Nadu", "age" : 27, "semesterMarks" : [ 65.6, 84, 71, 58 ] }, "salary" : 25000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606ac8d9a4cfca3993d52735"), "name" : "Sino", "branch" : "EEE", "joiningYear" : 2019, "language" : [ "Python", "PhP", "Php" ], "personal" : { "contactinfo" : 999995205, "state" : "Kerla", "age" : 27, "semesterMarks" : [ 85.6, 64, 86.4, 70 ] }, "salary" : 30000 }

db.college.find().sort({semesterMarks:1})
db.college.find().sort({semesterMarks:-1})
```

Answer (score 1):

`semesterMarks` is inside `personal`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({"personal.semesterMarks":1})
```